# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/modulerr?p0 Still not working please Check my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i am trying to code this and just Jump form 1 page to another page using routes but doesn't why its not working i search and tricks a lot but still failed please any one?

```js
index.html    

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <title>Angular Js</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="controller.js"></script>
 <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
----------


Controler.js 

var myRoute=angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myRoute.config(function($routeProvider){

 $routeProvider
 .when('/',{
  template:'Welcome to Home'

 })
 .when('/NewPage',{
  template:'This Is New Page Task'
 })
 otherwise('/',{
   redirectTo:'/'
 });



});
```

Comment: Are all ressourcs loaded correctly? Please check the network tab in your browser debugger.

Comment: Do or do not, there is no try.

Comment: Where do you define your templateUrl?

Comment: Definitely update the order of your scripts as suggested by @Sajeetharan below. Also, it may not be causing the error but remove the second mention of `html` in `<html html ` and also remove the last `</script>` tag which has no opening `<script>` tag. And update the question accordingly, then we know we're at least dealing with a valid document.

Comment: Problem Solved!! read my code carefully you will also find the error..
Thanks to all of you developers.. The error Was At otherwise('/',{
   redirectTo:'/'
 }); ) 
1. i forgot (. dot) and 2.here we cannot '/' , we just directly redirect to other page.
i just simply remove it and it runs wolaaaaa!!

Answer (score 1):

The order of references should be,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but it Still Not working.. i thing if any one solve this problem he/she will be a champion in angularJS

Comment: Thanks to YOu Sir.. The error Was At otherwise('/',{
   redirectTo:'/'
 }); ) 
1. i forgot (. dot) and 2.here we cannot '/' , we just directly redirect to other page.
i just simply remove it and it runs wolaaaaa!!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "route/one"
        })

    .when("/one", {
        templateUrl: "route/one"
    });

    });
```

templateUrl is the place where you define your view is...In here my view(one.cshtml) is in route folder. Try the following example. Its working example.

```
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#/AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </body>

<script>
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/AddNewOrder', {
            templateUrl: '/viewStudents.html',
            controller: 'AddOrderController'
        })

        .when('/ShowOrders', {
            templateUrl: '/Home.html',
            controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/viewStudents' });
  }]);

sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';
});

sampleApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';
});

</script>
```

Comment: Problem Solved!! read my code carefully you will also find the error..
Thanks for your efforts!!!.. The error Was At otherwise('/',{
   redirectTo:'/'
 }); ) 
1. i forgot (. dot) and 2.here we cannot '/' , we just directly redirect to other page.
i just simply remove it and it runs wolaaaaa!!